# Manually starting MessageListenerContainer prevents other listeners from starting - Why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

My spring boot application has several methods annotated with `@RabbitListener`. When the application starts, the corresponding consumers are registered with RabbitMQ.

When I add the following method to my code, only the consumers for the given listener (`idOfMySpecialListener`) are registered, all the others are not.

```
@EventListener 
public void onEnvironmentChangeEvent(EnvironmentChangeEvent event) {
    MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("idOfMySpecialListener");
    listenerContainer.start();
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I change the behavior to start all listeners (as without the `@EventListener`) and the specific one if it is not yet started.

Background: I wan't to start/stop `@RabbitListener`'s based on a property value change.

Comment: How are you preventing that one listener from starting? Just adding a listener like that won't affect `autoStartup`.

Comment: Can you crosscheck if this method is triggered before or after the methods annotated with `@Rabbitlistener`

Comment: @GaryRussell Somehow, adding `listenerContainer.start()` results in all other listeners (except the one affected by the method) not starting. If remove this one line, all listeners start successfully. I'm asking because I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: @pvpkiran I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry. As I understand it, `@RabbitListener` is triggered when a message arrives in the queue, and the `@EventListener` when a `EnvironmentChangeEvent` is triggered.

Comment: What you are suggesting is completely impossible - something else must be changed too. I suggest you compare DEBUG logs with and without the event listener. If you still can't figure it out; edit the question to include your complete configuration and/or a small app that reproduces the issue.